# SSIS - Execute 2nd task after completing 1st task

Tags: sql, ssis, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting to know SSIS, I apologize if the question is too simple.

I have 2 task, 1st is File System Task and 2nd is Execute Process Task.

File system task **COPY FOLDER** from 1 location to another where it's **CREATE NEW FOLDER** at destination and it's contain **ZIP file**.

Execute Process Task - Extract ZIP file.

I gave folder path in working directory where I want to extract zip file but that folder is not exist until 1st task is complete.

BTW, I am using Visual Studio 2008.

How can I execute both task?

Comment: Are you getting a validation error then?  If there is an error please post it.

Comment: Might look at changing the second task `DelayValidation=true` if its causing issues because the folder is not there when you execute

Comment: @Doolius Same thoughts here.

Comment: Since you don't mention it, it bears asking:   Have you got a precedence constraint between the two tasks?

Comment: Yea. I have precedence constraint between two tasks and delayed validation = false.

Comment: Thanks Doolius, IT works when I changed "DelayValidation = True".

Answer (score 0):

Connect the first task to the second task by the green line that will appear when you click on the first task. Just click the line and drag it to connect to the second task. Then right click on the line and choose 'completion' option.